# Doctrine 2 OneToOne entity mapping returns empty Entities

Tags: orm, doctrine, mapping, doctrine-orm

**The setup:**

I have the following code two entity models:

Account, representing the user account and has a foreign key to classroom.

```
<?php
namespace models;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Account
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Classroom")
     */
    public $classroom;
}
```

Classroom that represents the classroom a Student is enroled in.

```
<?php
namespace models;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Classroom
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    public $name;
}
```

**The problem:**

When I do `$account = $em->find('Account',$id);` I correctly get the account back from the database, but the `$account->classroom;` is an empty (not null) object. After experimenting a bit I tried adding the following command before the execution:

```
$em->getRepository('Classroom')->findAll().
```

Then I executed the `$em->find('Account', $id );` and the classroom object inside the account object returned correctly.

**Speculation:**

I assume that there is something wrong with the way entities are loaded and cached from the database, because if I load all the classroom objects (or the one associated with the account I) before I do my `find()`, then everything is fine.

As I'm beginner of PHP and Doctrine, I seek further opinions/help to solve that issue.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Doctrine Architecture Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/architecture.html):

> All persistent properties/field of any entity class should always be **private** or **protected**, otherwise **lazy-loading might not work as expected**.

Your `$classroom` property is `public`, which is probably why the association with the Classroom entity is not being lazy-loaded. You should change it to be `private` or `protected` (I recommend making all your Entity properties `protected`, for [various reasons](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)).

If that doesn't work, you could try setting the `fetch` attribute of your `OneToOne` association to EAGER, i.e.

```php
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Classroom", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $classroom;
```